# How to get 5Km radious of data from firebase using laravel 6 by using Kreait\Firebase provider

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, laravel-6

I am using laravel 6 and i have installed the provider  Kreait\Firebase in my laravel package. i have created connection with firebase realtime database already and getting the data from my database. but i need a support from your guys to get the data oa specific radius. pls help me thanx in advance. I have used below code to get the data

```
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(public_path().'/gogorides-f382d11-firebase-adminsdk-f8od3-46c809e52e.json');
    $firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->withDatabaseUri('https://gogorides-f382d.firebaseio.com/')
    ->create();

    $database  = $firebase->getDatabase();
    $reference = $database->getReference('drivers')->orderByChild('id')->limitToFirst(2)->getSnapshot()->getValue();
    print_r($reference);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database has no native support for such so-called geoqueries, that returns items within a certain range of a given point.

---

In many databases you would approximate this type of query by filtering a certain range of latitude and longitude. Something like:

```
latitude >= 120.0 && latitude <= 120.5 &&
longitude >= 78.3 && longitude <= 79.1
```

Unfortunately with Firebase Realtime Database you can only query on one property at a time. So without additional tricks, you can filter latitude *or* longitude in the database, and would have to filter the other one client side.

---

Luckily there is an add-on library for Firebase Realtime Database, called GeoFire, which adds the additional trickery. It adds an additional property to your database, that combines the latitude and longitude in a way that allows you to filter on both in a single query. Such a value is called a [Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash).

The GeoFire library is available for [iOS](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc), [Android](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-android), and [Web](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js). It unfortunately does no exist for PHP.

---

This leaves you with a few options:

1. Implement the logic inside the web client (in JavaScript), instead of on the web server (in PHP).
2. Port the logic of GeoFire over to PHP. If you're interested in that, I recommend checking out the video of my talk on [Geoqueries on Firebase and Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).

Comment: Thanx frank, let me try once with your concept